# On timer countdown image moves in c# xna

Tags: c#, image, if-statement, timer, xna

Here's my code: Variables:

```
//Game States
enum gameState
{
    gameLoading,
    mainMenu,
    gameOptions,
    levelSelect,
    gamePlaying,
}
gameState CurrentGameState = gameState.gameLoading;
```

In the `Update()` method:

```
    switch (CurrentGameState)
    {
        case gameState.gameLoading:
    //My gameLoading state logic here
    break;
    //And so on the other states, etc mainMenu, gameOptions, levelSelect, gamePlaying
```

And my `Draw()` method:

```
    switch (CurrentGameState)
    {
        case gameState.gameLoading:
    //Draw gameLoading state here
    break;
    //And so on the other states, etc mainMenu, gameOptions, levelSelect, gamePlaying
```

So I need something like `if()` maybe? and a timer that counts 30seconds and then it calls a `spriteBatch.Draw()` to draw my image on the screen.

Comment: What's the question? If for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems sound. You could implement it like this:

You could create a field: `float elapsedTime;`

Then in your `Update()` method, add the elapsed time to it:

```
elapsedTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
```

And then in your `Draw()` method:

```
if (elapsedTime >= 30.0)
{
    // Draw the image
}
```